# Spark count not giving correct results

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, count

I am new to spark and recently learned that it will do all transformations when an action is called. While searching for it, I found a simple code to test it and the results are not as expected.

Here is the code

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from os import system as ossystem
import time

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[4]").getOrCreate()
txtfile= spark.read.text("./temp.txt")
print(txtfile.count())

time.sleep(10)

print(txtfile.count())
```

When the `sleep` executes, I run the command `echo "1\n2\n3" >> temp.txt` from another terminal to add three more lines to the file. The output of the PySpark code is as follows.

```
2
3
```

It prints `3` instead of `5`. Why so? Is the re-computation not working properly? If I explicitly put the dataframe formation before the second count, then it works as follows.

```py
txtfile= spark.read.text("./temp.txt")
print(txtfile.count())

time.sleep(10)

txtfile= spark.read.text("./temp.txt")
print(txtfile.count())
```

Output

```
2
5
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm running this on a single machine.